# Is asymmetric encryption is safe on the Internet? Can't a hacker just pose as a valid user?

Tags: encryption, rsa, asymmetric

**When I read the RSA asymmetric encryption:**

[image]

**In the environment:**

**Rules are:**
blue boy, red girl, and black men.

blue boy and red girl all have their own public key (blue) and private key (red).

---

**In the first step:**

> blue boy signs the `plaintext(1)`, sends the `plaintext(1)`, `RSA.sign(1)` and 
>   `blue public key` to red girl; then red girl can use the `blue public key` sign the `plaintext(1)`, to compare the received `RSA.sign(1)` and check the data whether is right.

**I have two questions:**

1. What's the purpose of the first step?
2. The black men can truncate the network, then send red girl `3 + RSA.sign(3)` + `black public key` using blue boy's name. Why is this safe?

Comment: I think this could be better suited to crypto over security stackexchange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have prior knowledge of the keys, and no secure channel or other means for verifying keys, then it of course breaks down in the face of an attacker who can modify messages.

But. We have certificate authorities on the internet that we trust. We trust that they only issue a key for the domain example.org to the entity that can demonstrate control over example.org in some way.

The keys of those certificate authorities is embedded in many pieces of modern software, e.g. Firefox, Windows, Linux distributions, Java and so forth. The certificate used by example.org will be signed by the CA, making it impossible to fake it. As the certificate of the CA is pre-distributed, it can't be intercepted by a trivial MiTM-attack.

In organizations, a private Public Key Infrastructure may be configured, so that the organization can issue key material them self, and configure trust more flexibly than by relying on external trust agencies.

Software such as GPG relies not on central agencies, but rather a [web of trust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust). I may know Bob, so I meet him and sign his key with mine. You may know Alice, who knows me, and also as signed my key. This way you can establish trust to a key you acquired over an insecure channel.

For private citizens, you can verify a key by e.g. phoning the person, and checking that the fingerprint is equal to what it should be. The finger print is not secret, so it does not matter if anyone listens in on this conversation; they will learn naught, but it will allow you to verify the key.